# How to implement API in a project

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm developing an application for iPhone as my master thesis and it is my first experience with programming.
I'm doing an app that will scan barcode, taking ouf from code digits behind it, and then I need to send them to open source database and receive an answer with list of ingredients back.
So this info I found on one internet site.
The question is how I can implement THIS into my program?

It is possible to open the EAN database access from your own applications out of an EAN-query to perform.
This should happen with a simple HTTP GET request, the following format:

```
http://openean.kaufkauf.net/?ean = [ean] & & cmd = query queryid = [userid]
[Ean] here is the eight-or thirteen-digit EAN to be queried. How do you get a User ID 
[userid] for the field "queryid" can be found below.
```

The query was successful, you will receive data in text format (MIME type text / plain) back, which can look like this:

```
error = 0 
name = Natural mineral 
bath Vilbeler name = detail RIED source 
vendor = H. Krone GmbH & CO.. KG 
= maincat drinks, alcohol 
subcat = 
descr = Natural mineral water carbonated 
origin = Germany 
= 25% validated
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  SO is more suited to specific programming related questions.  Perhaps you can edit the question and state what you have tried and not just "how do you implement this application?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the result stored into a string by doing the following

```
//Replace each var with your strings
NSString *request=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://openean.kaufkauf.net/?ean=%@&cmd=%@&queryid=%@%@",EANString,queryString,userIDString,EANString];
NSURL *urequest=[NSURL URLWithString:request];

//Assuming you are using UTF8StringEncoding
NSString *result=[[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:urequest encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

//parse the result to get your data

//After you stop using result you can release it
[result release];
```

If you need further explanation on this let me know.

Edit:

I really don't know about the codes you are using nor about the SDK, though all you need to do after you have your scanner working is to get 3 pieces of data (this to construct your HTTPRequest) and those are EAN, query and userid.

After you have done this you will have to perform the request (first 2 lines of the code) this after you have replaced the values with your recently acquired data (EAN, query and userid).

Then all you have to do is to parse your results; the request will return you a string with the form of the quote from your post, so you will have to go through the string taking whatever you need from it.

Hopefully this was a bit more clear.

Comment: Dear El Developer, thank you very much for your answer. I have now some more questions, if it's possible) As a barcode scanner, I've also took an open source sdk which name is ZBar sdk. It takes a picture of a product barcode and shows a digits behind, and exactly this digits I should send with this request upstairs. So where I should put them? To: //parse the result to get your data?

Comment: And this is how I've done it:                      `ZBarReaderViewController *reader = [ZBarReaderViewController new];` `reader.readerDelegate = self;`                          `[reader.scanner setSymbology: ZBAR_QRCODE
                config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE
                to: 0];`
`reader.readerView.zoom = 1.0;`                                  `[self presentModalViewController: reader
      animated: YES];`

Comment: `- (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController*) reader
 didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary*) info
{
    id<NSFastEnumeration> results =
        [info objectForKey: ZBarReaderControllerResults];
    UIImage *image =
        [info objectForKey: UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];`

Comment: This ZBar sdk:[link](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/sdkdoc/) So how it is possible to take out result from scanner and where to put it to send to the web server? Thanks a lot. Hope to hear from you soon.

Comment: Thanks))) But I knew this, actually I wanted to know how to take out for example EAN, it appears on the display, but how I can took it out in the same time and put it inside my request, maybe you know such code? And second, should I do some View for received information, to implement some connection to interface? Thanks a lot one more time)